# Error When I try to add dynamically component with angular2 using drag and drop

Tags: typescript, angular, drag-and-drop

this is my directives to drag and drop

I want when I apply my drag and drop to add a component to my div 
I did the some things after event click but now I how to change it to drag and drop

```
import {
    Directive, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef, Input, Renderer, ViewContainerRef, ViewChild, ComponentResolver,
    ComponentRef
} from '@angular/core';
import {Div444} from "../gridmanager/div4-4-4.component";
declare var jQuery:JQueryStatic;

@Directive({
    selector: '[dnd_drag_grid]',
    host: {
        '(dragstart)': 'onDragStart($event)',
        '(dragend)': 'onDragEnd($event)',
        '(drag)': 'onDrag($event)',
    }
})
export class dnd_drag_grid {

    elementDrag:HTMLElement;


    @Input("drag") drag;

    set draggable(value:boolean) {
        this.drag = !!value;
    }

    elem:HTMLElement;

    constructor(private componentRef:ComponentRef, private resolver:ComponentResolver,
                private el:ElementRef, private renderer:Renderer) {
        this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'draggable', 'true');
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'cursor', 'move');
    }

    onDrag(event:MouseEvent) {
        console.log("  -----onDrag---- " + this.drag);
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'border-style', 'dotted');

    }

    onDragEnd(event:Event) {
        console.log("  -----DragEnd---- " + this.drag);
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'border', 'none');

    }

    onDragStart(event:DragEvent) {
        console.log("  ----DragStart----- " + this.drag);
        this.elementDrag = this.el.nativeElement;
    }

}

@Directive({
    selector: '[dnd_drop_grid]',
    host: {

        '(dragover)': 'onAllowDrop($event)',
        '(drop)': 'onDrop($event)',
        '(dragleave)': 'ondragleave($event)',
        '(dragenter)': 'onDragEnter($event)'
    }
})
export class dnd_drop_grid {
    elementDrop:HTMLElement;

    @Input("drop") drop;
    @Input("target") target;


    set droppable(value:boolean) {
        this.drop = !!value;
    }
    set setTarget(value:string) {
        this.target = value;
    }

    elem:HTMLElement;
    @ViewChild('', {read: ViewContainerRef}) component_target;

    constructor(private componentRef:ComponentRef, private resolver:ComponentResolver,
                private el:ElementRef, private renderer:Renderer) {
        console.log("target "+ this.target);

    }


    onAllowDrop(event:DragEvent) {
        this.component_target = this.target;
        console.log("target "+ this.target);
        console.log("on allow drop ");
        event.preventDefault();
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'borderStyle', 'dotted');
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'borderColor', 'red');

    }

    ondragleave(event:DragEvent) {
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'borderStyle', 'bridge');
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'borderColor', 'white');
        console.log("target "+ this.target);

    }

    onDragEnter(event:Event) {
        console.log("target "+ this.target);

    }

    onDrop(event:DragEvent) {
        console.log("target "+ this.target);

        this.elementDrop = this.el.nativeElement;
        event.preventDefault();
        this.resolver.resolveComponent(Div444).then((factory) => {
            this.componentRef = this.component_target.createComponent(factory);
        });
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'borderStyle', 'bridge');
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'borderColor', 'white');
        console.log("is dropped !");

    }


}
```

and I add this in my template .html

```
<li dnd_drag_grid drag="true">Div 4-4-4</li>
<div dnd_drop_grid target="val" drop="true" class="page" id="content" size="A4" layout="portrait" >
                <div  #val hidden></div>
            </div>
```

this is my error

```
 Unhandled Promise rejection: _this.component_target.createComponent is not a function ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: _this.component_target.createComponent is not a function(…)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
target="val"
```

assigns the string `val` to `@Input("target") target;`

I assume what you want is

```
[target]="valVcr"
```

and in the parent component

```
@ViewChild('val', {read: ViewContainerRef}) valVcr:ViewContainerRef;`
```

to get the `ViewContainerRef` from `val` assigned to `target`

Comment: however I added square bracket or I add  @ViewChild('val'', {read: ViewContainerRef}) component_target;
 I get the some error
the problem is when I call method createComponent

Comment: I missed the `#val` and assumed you are assigning the property `val` from the component class with an unknown (to me value). I updated my answer. The problem is that `val` returns an `ElementRef` but `createComponent` requires a `ViewContainerRef`. You need the intermediate step using `@ViewChild()` to get the `ViewContainerRef` instead.

Comment: I dont understand when I add square bracket I show target in console.log I get HTMLDivELement and without it I get string (val)

Can you give me please some indication how to intermediate between ViewChild and ViewContainerRef

Comment: Without `[]` Angular doesn't do anything with it. `target="val"` in Angular2 is the same as if you add it to a static `index.html` (without any JS or framework).

Comment: Alternatively you can use `{{}}` in the value, then Angular also processes it, but assigns the stringified value.

Comment: If I can say I convert HTMLDivElement to String ?

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. What purpose would `HTMLDivElement` fulfill as string?

Comment: Can you give me and example from plunker to show me how to do it
please 
because I have not really understood what you mean thanks

Comment: What about you build a Plunker and then I jump in for the last step to fix the issue if you can't make it work on your own. (Plunker template https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html)

Comment: I tried to create it here is

http://plnkr.co/edit/NRmg2AuavGKG72W1Y44A?p=preview

Comment: I fixed a few issues http://plnkr.co/edit/os6MXAdUuN650LdtPRIK?p=preview There is a `dnd_drag` directive missing.

Comment: you can remove it from div4-4-4
http://plnkr.co/edit/NRmg2AuavGKG72W1Y44A?p=preview

Comment: Please fix the plunker so that it reproduces the problem. I don't want to debug missing closing tags for you http://plnkr.co/edit/os6MXAdUuN650LdtPRIK?p=preview

Comment: when I add a directive into tag <li> to apply my drag and drop plunker not show text inside tag !

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/ITj7cWsqsknGs2E5YY8V?p=preview I fixed a few more things. What is `@ViewChild('', {read: ViewContainerRef}) component_target;` supposed to do? An empty query string won't do anything meaningful.

Comment: I want to make a value of ViewChild configurable
I mean I want to change this value when I change input target 
thats way I affect targtet to component_target

when I do my drag and drop from tag <li> to <div> where I have ViewChild (#val) I want that component Div4-4-4 be added

Comment: There is no way to make the query part configurable. This needs to be static text. You need to find another way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Even if the static way is not working for the first time I need just to add my component (like this     @ViewChild('val', {read: ViewContainerRef}) component_target; )
but I get error TypeError: Cannot read property 'createComponent' of undefined

Comment: I don't get this error in the Plunker link I posted above (see AppComponent). There needs to be an element with a `#val` template variable in the template for `@ViewChild('val', ...)` to work

Comment: I tried it it's not working the effect of drag and drop is work correctly but the component div4-4-4 is not added in the ViewChild (#val)

Comment: Can you post a Plunker link that allows to reproduce what the issue you're talking about?

Comment: this is a plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/NRmg2AuavGKG72W1Y44A?p=preview

you can open console to see the error when he want create Component Div444 from method onDrop

Comment: The `dnd_drop_grid` component doesn't have an element with a `#val` template variable, this is why `@ViewChild()` doesn't find one.

Comment: Should I add #val in the some tag were I add dnd_drop_drid ?
can you help me please to add it in the div tag
what I must edit or add in dnd_drop_drif Directive to make it work

Comment: You can only query in the template of a component using `@ViewChild()`. Sorry, I don't have that much time today to provide extensive support.